# Flask SocketIO disconnect on OS Date Change

Tags: date, flask, time, socket.io, clock

I have a Web application that is using Flask-socketIO.

```
__init__.py
import flask
import flask_socketio

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
socketio = flask_socketio.SocketIO()
socketio.init_app(app, manage_session=False)
```

I have this in my manage.py

```
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

I have this in my socket_IO.py

```
@WebApp.socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/all')
def disconnect():
    """Socket disconnected."""
    print('Disconnected')
```

If i now set the system clock ( Ubuntu 16.04 ) for example 1 day forward i get socket disconnect. I can set the clock backwards to whatever i want it does not effect the socket.

What i expect to happen is for the socket not to fire the disconnect function on a change in the system clock.

Does flask-socketIO use the system clock and because of that makes the socket disconnect if it's set forward and not backwards?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post what you have tried. This is just an open ended question while its like this.

Comment: Im new to flask and socketio so not really sure what to try. What ive tried is setting pingInterval and pingTimeout. it dsn't seem to do anything when setting it for longer times. 

One more thing i have noticed is that if i set the time to for example 25 days from now. Then it gets disconnected. I then refresh the page and try to set it to 20 days from now. This works (always works to set it back in time). If i then again set it forward from that date to 23rd it also works.

It only disconnects if i set the time forward to a point in time ive never set it before.

Comment: Post a code of what you've tried and where its failing. That way, you'll be able to get a good answer

Comment: @Pokpe You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? What is the expected result? Can you show us some code? Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: @Opsse I have now updated the question with some more information of what i expect and what is happening. Also added some code. Hope this helps, If there is anything more you might need let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making a socket's timeout counter system clock independent?

Comment: I have a request sent to the back-end where i have a python sub-process do the change in system clock. If the socket disconnects at that point i dont get an response from the back-end that the clock was changed or any other request/response that i might want to send untill the socket reconnects again. @Fian

Comment: In that case, I can't add anything more to your question, but the whole need to change system clock seems pretty strange, maybe you should revise it.